# rmdir on my machine doesn't have the -r argument

Tags: 12.04, command-line, uninstall, directory

I checked the man page for it using `man rmdir` and all it has is `--ignore-fail-on-non-empty`, `-p`, `-v`, `--help`, and `--version`. What am I missing?

I'm using Ubuntu 12.04 LTS

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`rmdir` has no `-r` option. The purpose of `rmdir` is to delete only *empty* directories.

If you want to delete *non-empty* directories, that's when you'll use the `-r` option of the command `rm`.

- Delete *empty* directory called *emptydir*:

  ```
  $ rmdir emptydir
  ```
- If directory *nonemptydir* is non-empty, you'll have an error:

  ```
  $ rmdir nonemptydir
  rmdir: failed to remove `nonemptydir': Directory not empty
  ```
- To delete *non-empty* directory *nonemptydir*:

  ```
  $ rm -r nonemptydir
  ```

Hope this helps!

Comment: OK thanks. Some of the websites I found when googling this had `rmdir -r` for some reason, or maybe its just because I've been awake all night :P